# Instantiate factory with parameters angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I do use factory as resouce provider in this way

```
angular.module('resources.users').factory('Users', ['serverResource', function (serverResource) {

    return serverResource('users');
}]);
```

where server resource provides server resource for REST API... 
but there is api for invoice items in this form */invoices/{invoice_id}/item/* so I need to pass variable in factory constructor.

I found out that it is possible to do this way:

```
angular.module('resources.invoiceItem').factory('InvoiceItem', ['serverResource', function (serverResource) {

    return function (invoiceID) {

        if(!angular.isNumber(invoiceID)) {
            console.log('InvoiceID has to be number!');

            return null;
        }

        return serverResource('invoices/' + invoiceID + '/item');
    }
}]);
```

and then instantiate like this

```
var insertedItem = new InvoiceItem(inserted_id);
```

everything seems ok, even in debuger I can method for crud like $save,$ saveOrUpdate, $update or $remove (provide by server resource) but when I called

```
insertedItem.$saveOrUpdate(function(){}, function(){}, function(){}, function(){});
```

I've got error **undefined is not a function** and I don't understand why? I also don't understad why console.log(insertedItem) returns me

```
function (data) {
     angular.extend(this, data);
}
```

I would expect instance of serverResource...

So my question is what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot for any response

EDIT: plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/VkZo5kbiNAyudb0yFPhu

Comment: Try to recreate in a fiddle.

Comment: plunker added to question

Comment: there is no `$saveOrUpdate` function

Comment: there was method $save, I though for example excact naming is not neccessary, so I renamed it to $saveOrUpdate

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an object, but you return the constructor function.

Change `return Resource` to return `new Resource` in the `serverResource` factory.

Edit:

Continuing the comments, try this:

```
return function() {
        return serverResource('invoices');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works, but won't it mess simple resources like this http://pastebin.com/ZMEVR1Jb ? It seems to as problem, see this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/3ypFMfN5l4JgVuNNkk02

Comment: @blazek idk what you are trying to do. you can't expect a constructor function that you return from the first factory to behave the same as an object you return from the second.

Comment: I have server resource for standart rest api (for example: /invoices/ - GET, POST, PUT, DELETE), but I have items for each invoice and api is like (/invoices/{invoiceID}/) so I need to somehow pass invoice id into rest address, this is the only exception in my api all others are in standart form but I don't know how to do it with factory... sorry for my possible bad explanation

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but I'm afraid this will not solve my problem...I just need pass parameter (i need that serverResource object..) to factory or use better component but as beginner I'm not sure which one...

Comment: @blazek sorry, I can't figure out what you want.